# Apply dynamic objects to storyboards

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have the following `storyboard` setup in an `xaml` file

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" >
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath 
            Duration="0:0:3"  
            Source="X" 

            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" 
            >
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M1.5,-18.667014 L8.1669813,-54.00002 L31.833186,-94.666719 L60.166999,-116.33299"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>

        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath 
            Duration="0:0:3"   
            Source="Y"

            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" 
            >

            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M1.5,-18.667014 L8.1669813,-54.00002 L31.833186,-94.666719 L60.166999,-116.33299"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>

        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

And in the same `xaml` file I have a `Rectangle` to use as an object to move on a path.

```
      <Rectangle x:Name="ObjectToMove" Height="31" Canvas.Left="-316.5" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="431.5" Width="42" Fill="#FFDA6C11" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
```

In code I do this.

```
 var sub1 = FindResource("Storyboard1") as Storyboard;
 sub1.Begin(ObjectToMove);
```

So far things work just fine.

**The problem**

Instead of having `ObjectToMove` statically setup in `xaml` I want to be able to have more dynamic setup and apply it from code using `UserControl`. So I have setup a `UserControl`.

And Instead of this
`sub1.Begin(ObjectToMove)`

I did this

`sub1.Begin(new Tray());`

As soon I hit the animation button I get

> '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[3].(2)'.

What I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

**Update #1 - based on comment**

I have the `tray.xaml` like this.Not sure though.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Tray"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

         >
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="58" Width="50">
    <!--<Rectangle Fill="#FFD4CEC8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="58" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50"/>-->

    <Rectangle x:Name="ObjectToMove" Height="31" Canvas.Left="-316.5" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="431.5" Width="42" Fill="Aqua" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="0,0,8,27">

        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
    </Rectangle>

</Grid>
```

**Update #2 - Based on given answers**

The goal is to have several storyboards setup (lets say 7 storyboards), but must be able to apply objects dynamically to those storyboards. So I must have control on each storyboard and able feed those storyboards with objects doing this in code.

**Example**

When first the animation starts, an object ( lets call it object#1 ) moves on the path. When object#1 is just few seconds in his animation, I must be able to push/feed another object (lets call this object #2) to the same storyboard. So now we have 2 objects on the storyboard visible moving on the path one after the other. Just like a conveyor belt. The two objects have time-gap between them ( I will take care of this, don't worry about this).

Notes: I will have `completed` method in the storyboards, which trigges as soon  as the first storyboard is finished. Doing this I should have sequence alike animation and plus control over the storyboads and objects.

Hopefully the above example makes some sense.

Comment: It seems you have to ensure what all objects you are trying to animate have required for animation properties (talking about `RenderTransformGroup`). You have to add one to `Tray` somehow.

Comment: @Sinatr I have updated the question. I am not sure if this is the right way..? Any further ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry dude, been super busy lately...but let's get you sorted real quick since it's Friday and we both deserve beers in our near future. :)

So... You want to get your Storyboards to be generic so you don't have to keep targeting specific named objects right? Well let's do that then by opening up the entire `TargetType` to accept our bidding and make these little buggers behave.

Using from the example I gave you on the last one I'm going to re-use the same path data etc. Except notice that we've taken all the explicit render declarations from the sole object and instead made them implicit. This way, it doesn't care which `Rectangle` it's hitting...if it's a `Rectangle` then it's getting moved because we've moved all of it over into an agnostic style controlling the `TargetType` instead of a `TargetName` like this;

```
<Canvas x:Name="Main" Height="1025" Width="1025">
  <Canvas.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
      <Style.Resources>
        <!-- All your base are belong to us. -->
        <Storyboard x:Key="Weeeee" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
          <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:3" Source="X" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
              <PathGeometry Figures="M0.83299852,-4.019 L0.83299852,0.6089829 L0.61794496,0.94214186 C-7.6701996,14.489389 -12.443,30.392629 -12.443001,47.403001 C-12.443,96.887715 27.948303,137.003 77.773499,137.003 C113.58536,137.003 144.52365,116.27938 159.09367,86.248303 L159.90265,84.471135 L380.931,84.471135 L380.931,86.871121 L160.63918,86.871121 L160.4838,87.217053 C145.62575,118.25356 114.07582,139.671 77.556,139.671 C26.745804,139.671 -14.444,98.212666 -14.444,47.071218 C-14.444,29.491346 -9.5768454,13.055669 -1.124851,-0.94513857 z"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
          </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
          <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:3" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
              <PathGeometry Figures="M0.83299852,-4.019 L0.83299852,0.6089829 L0.61794496,0.94214186 C-7.6701996,14.489389 -12.443,30.392629 -12.443001,47.403001 C-12.443,96.887715 27.948303,137.003 77.773499,137.003 C113.58536,137.003 144.52365,116.27938 159.09367,86.248303 L159.90265,84.471135 L380.931,84.471135 L380.931,86.871121 L160.63918,86.871121 L160.4838,87.217053 C145.62575,118.25356 114.07582,139.671 77.556,139.671 C26.745804,139.671 -14.444,98.212666 -14.444,47.071218 C-14.444,29.491346 -9.5768454,13.055669 -1.124851,-0.94513857 z"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
          </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
        </Storyboard>
      </Style.Resources>

      <!-- Because we don't really care what the parent is or where it lives anyway do we? -->
      <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
          <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Weeeee}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>

      <!-- Whaaaa? We can do this?? Hell yes we can... -->
      <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
      <Setter Property="Rectangle.RenderTransform">
        <Setter.Value>
          <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
          </TransformGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>

   </Style>

  </Canvas.Resources>

  <Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <MatrixTransform Matrix="1.25 0 0 -1.25 -197.1231 961.58875"/>
  </Canvas.RenderTransform>

  <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path139746" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="399.4" Canvas.Top="-172.6">
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry Figures="m 66.611178 552.33853 c -4.36996 0.6305 -8.8334 0.97293 -13.3752 0.97293 -18.11465 0 -35.027 -5.21161 -49.34949 -14.18974 l 21.64732 -36.67733 c 8.2963 5.25686 18.12667 8.31294 28.67512 8.31294 2.7121 0 5.37755 -0.20365 7.98106 -0.59283 l 2.23539 -0.38916 c 4.72288 -0.91109 9.2226 -2.43913 13.41755 -4.49964 l 35.933612 77.65818 c -12.53504 5.94167 -26.095762 10.06571 -40.347392 12.0342 0 0 -2.27764 -21.55688 -4.54327 -42.98252 l -2.2747 0.35297 z" FillRule="nonzero"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="401" Canvas.Top="-173" >
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry x:Name="path139750" Figures="m -21.311892 515.98804 c -11.7053 -15.57594 -18.6547 -34.92004 -18.6622 -55.85694 l 35.53987 0 5.06525 -0.024 c 0.63507 11.4535 4.86922 21.94 11.58023 30.3706 l 1.44647 1.7423 c 2.94008 3.3894 6.29329 6.4077 9.98888 8.9736 l -43.53754 73.76488 c -13.18956 -8.30539 -24.88746 -18.76176 -34.60186 -30.87743 0 0 17.3968 -13.23944 34.61076 -26.3386 l -1.42986 -1.75428 z" FillRule="nonzero"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path139780" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="401.4" Canvas.Top="-167.6">
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry Figures="m 214.75854 460.1016 94.92962 0 0 69.86866 -94.92962 0 0 -69.86866 z" FillRule="nonzero"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path139784" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="401.4" Canvas.Top="-167.6">
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry Figures="m 211.64803 529.825 -36.87191 0 -62.32503 -69.72236 100.95576 0 0 69.74499 -1.75882 -0.0226 z" FillRule="nonzero"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Top="-173" Canvas.Left="401">
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry x:Name="path139798" Figures="m -41.482092 460.131 -43.5377 0 c 0.6744 30.93022 11.4414 59.36853 29.1278 82.17137 l 33.3799 -25.40184 c -11.9001 -15.82789 -18.9641 -35.4887 -18.97 -56.76953" FillRule="nonzero"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path139802" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="399.4" Canvas.Top="-172.6">
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry Figures="m 139.82292 494.54117 c -13.01467 -14.5593 -25.97803 -29.06131 -30.40076 -34.00892 0 0 -2.72123 28.49563 -29.566602 43.70507 l 17.54746 37.92328 c 19.158502 -10.35383 34.278952 -27.22704 42.419902 -47.61943" FillRule="nonzero"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path139806" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="399.4" Canvas.Top="-172.6">
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry Figures="m 98.037008 543.53024 17.776782 38.41802 c 23.1211 -11.42479 42.62202 -29.06882 56.29587 -50.76297 l 0.18403 -0.31676 c 0 0 -15.53072 -17.37553 -31.34655 -35.06934 -8.34762 20.43762 -23.62341 37.33197 -42.910132 47.73105" FillRule="nonzero"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
  <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path139810" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="399.4" Canvas.Top="-172.6">
    <Path.Data>
      <PathGeometry Figures="m 53.235488 554.82033 c -18.39362 0 -35.56859 -5.28853 -50.11595 -14.3994 l -21.08756 35.73002 c 21.04842 12.78086 45.75185 20.14348 72.17809 20.14348 5.74697 0 11.40815 -0.36201 16.97265 -1.03931 l -4.37747 -41.4213 c -4.43321 0.63805 -8.96144 0.98651 -13.56976 0.98651" FillRule="nonzero"/>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>

  <!-- Trajectory -->
  <Path Data="M16.276999,1 L16.276999,5.627983 16.061945,5.9611419 C7.7738004,19.508389 3.0009999,35.41163 3.000999,52.422002 3.0009999,101.90672 43.392303,142.022 93.217499,142.022 129.02936,142.022 159.96765,121.29839 174.53767,91.267304 L175.34665,89.490136 396.375,89.490136 396.375,91.890122 176.08318,91.890122 175.9278,92.236054 C161.06975,123.27256 129.51982,144.69 93,144.69 42.189804,144.69 1,103.23167 1,52.090218 1,34.510346 5.8671546,18.07467 14.319149,4.0738615 z" Fill="#7F000000" Height="145.69" Canvas.Left="360.056" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Canvas.Top="236.648" Width="397.375"/>

  <!-- Because I like to move it, move it ~~ Add as many as you like, however you like, from wherever you like. -->
  <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Height="36" Stroke="Black" Width="41" Canvas.Left="355" Canvas.Top="223.667"/>

</Canvas>
```

You'll notice I left much of it the same from the previous example.... Now, it doesn't care how many `Rectangle` objects there are. Or when or how they're added. When one appears, we move it like a boss.

Hope this helps and have a great weekend amigo, cheers! :)

Oh and PS, having that xmlns namespace on every single Path isn't necessary. If you wanted to clean up your stuff a bit you could accomplish the same thing with one line by changing each instance of this;

```
<Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path139746" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="399.4" Canvas.Top="-172.6">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry Figures="m 66.611178 552.33853 ... z" FillRule="nonzero"/>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

to this;

```
<Path Name="path139746" Fill="#FFD3BC5F" Canvas.Left="399.4" Canvas.Top="-172.6" Data="m 66.611178 552.33853 ..... z"/>
```

...unless there is some specific reason to have it all long?

Another tip would be, if you don't need Transform group, just hit a specific transform like Translate.

**ADDENDUM:**

Say you wanted to use that Style+Elsewhere. The way it's constructed right now is just for the sake of quick modular example. You could however for example just plop the whole thing in say resource dictionary and give it in an `x:Key` for reference. So if you threw it in the Resource dict then the first line would become something like;

```
<Style x:Key="NiftyRectangleAnim" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
```

So now you would have it in one spot, say you wanted to apply it to all Rectangle instances on a user control. Well then you would just add something like this;

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NiftyRectangleAnim}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then all Rectangles as they're available on that UserControl would inherit that style and animate.

Or say you just want to use the Storyboard, then you would pull it out of the style, and put it in some resources somewhere else where they can be referenced in the hierarchy. Like (in pseudo) you could throw this bit wherever it needs inherited from;

```
<Blah.Resources>
   <Storyboard x:Key="Weeeee"............./>
</Blah.Resources>
```

and apply with the Storyboard.Begin way you were using. You would still apply the rest of the style to Rectangle object (without the Style.Triggers included) so they would all get the necessary Transform declarations but the Storyboard doesn't necessarily have to be included INSIDE the Style template.

Hopefully makes a little more sense, it's a somewhat difficult concept to explain so verbosely but no you don't necessarily HAVE to have the storyboard in the Style.Resources, I just did that so you could copy/paste the whole thing in a window and see it go. You'll need to be somewhat experienced with using Resources/inheritance hierarchies and stuff for what you're trying to do either way though.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your answer seems promissing, although I wasn't able to find the storyboard if it is within the boundaries of a`style`. I tried this  ` var sub1 = FindResource("Storyboard1") as Storyboard;` I have updated the post, and hopefully might shed some more light to what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: @user3641381 You plop your Storyboard anywhere you need to so they can be hit by it within the context required. As you add items that match the TargetType then the Storyboard should apply. In this case if you added another Rectangle say 2s after the first one, then it should follow at 2s behind the first one, and so on, and so on.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean by "You plop your storyboard anywhere..."  I can't just put it outside <Style.Resources> It won't apply the animation... It needs to be inside the <style> boundaries, right?

Comment: @user3641381 So as it sits, the Storyboard just happens to sit in the Style.Resources, because thanks to the inheritance hierarchy when the Style.Triggers fires off it can find it immediately. However you could have that same Storyboard available at the Container level, the parent window, the project, the solution, wherever since it's a StaticResource. Actually here hang on let me just update the answer, one sec....

Comment: Cool so did you get it sorted?

Comment: Chris W. I gave it a try, Chris. Unfortunately I wasn't able to reach my desired situation :( After that I did not want to keep asking you for changes,  you already put a lot of effort into this. So I have decided to accept your given answer - it is a great answer. Maybe it's just me not getting it :(

Answer (score 0):

Since your storyboard animations don't have a target, then it tries to animate the `TranslateTransform.Y` on the root object but it doesn't have `RenderTransform` property set. In order to run the storyboard on a new Tray object, you'll need to code it as so:

```
sub1.Begin(new Tray().ObjectToMove);
```

This will run the storyboad on the `ObjectToMove` object in the new Tray rather than on the Tray itself.

Comment: I think his overall goal was to make the behavior apply to the targettype as opposed to a specific named object, unless I read it wrong.

Comment: @ChrisW. I figured since the OP tried to do this `sub1.Begin(new Tray());` he was okay with keeping the storyboard as it is. But then again, I could have read it wrong and missed his intentions.

Comment: Eh, I don't have any experience using Tray really so it wouldn't surprise me if I'm just fumbling the intent. Oh well, I'm sure he'll let us know one way or another lol. Have a great weekend!

Comment: @evanb I gave a try as well, but nothing was happening..? Any ideas? Thanks!